# Does somebody knows how to tweak , animation for sprite in Construct 2

Tags: construct-2

How to loop sprite animation, when the keyboard key (right and left) are pressed. And when the sprite stops on the contrary stop animation. PS: I have only animations 0 and 1.

What I tried on the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEERu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the "On Left Arrow pressed" which is an On Trigger command (i.e., executed only once), you can use the "On Left arrow is down" which will execute every tick while the condition is true.